# LeadTools SDK implementation in iOS

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, leadtools-sdk

Actually I need to implement MICR, OCR code read from Cheque in iOS via LeadTools. But I am not able to get the LeadTools iOS tutorial for Beginners so that I can start the implementation. Please help me to know how to start LeadTools sdk implementation in iOS.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is not clear from your question whether you found the tutorial but faced problems with it, or you haven't found it to begin with.

Either way, here's the best approach to implementing OCR and MICR recognition on iOS using LEADTOOLS:

First you need to install the OSX/iOS toolkit package. If you don't already own the toolkit, you can download the free evaluation edition from www.leadtools.com

After that, follow this tutorial:
https://www.leadtools.com/help/leadtools/v18/dh/to/leadtools.topics~leadtools.topics.gettingstartedwithleadtoolsforiososx.html

If you run into problems with any step or get errors when you complete the tutorial contact LEAD support with full details of the problem.

Once you get the starting tutorial up and running, move to the 2 demos for OCR and MICR. Their source code is installed with the package in these locations:

- Examples/Xcode/iOS/OcrDemo
- Examples/Xcode/iOS/MicrDemo